# Make Django Data-Url Attribute string form to work in .prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a django web app (esr_submit) that has a form and the ability to upload files. When a file is uploaded (using fileupload jquery), the list of uploaded files needs updated via a prepend action, replicating the html for the  and . The button contains a data-url attribute which calls on the django url and its respective view to accomplish the delete action. How do I make the data-url attribute a string so the script works?

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ServiceRequestForm, FileForm
from .models import RequestAttachment
from django.http import JsonResponse


def delete_file(request, pk):if request.method == 'POST':
        file = RequestAttachment.objects.get(pk=pk)
        file.delete()
    return redirect('/esr_submit/files')


def esr_submit(request):
    files = RequestAttachment.objects.all()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        initial_data = {'first_name': request.user.first_name,
                        'last_name': request.user.last_name,
                        'email': request.user.email,
                        'contact': request.user.phone,
                        }
        request_form = ServiceRequestForm(initial=initial_data)
    else:
        request_form = ServiceRequestForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'submit_request' in request.POST:
            request_form = ServiceRequestForm(request.POST)
            if request_form.is_valid():
                request_form.save()
                return redirect('/esr_submit/')
            else:
                print(request_form.errors)
                return redirect('/esr_submit/')

        if 'file' in request.FILES:
            form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                file = form.save()
                data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': file.file.name, 'url': file.file.url}
            else:
                data = {'is_valid': False}
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            print("not a file form")
    else:
        files_list = RequestAttachment.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'esr_submit/esr_submit.html',
                      {'request_form': request_form,
                       'files': files,
                       'photos': files_list
                       }
                      )
```

```
urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.esr_submit, name='esr_submit'),
    path('files/', views.file_list, name='file_list'),
    path('files/<int:pk>/', views.delete_file, name='delete_file'),
```

```
esr_submit.html

{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% block title %}
Submit an ESR
{% endblock %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<head>

</head>
<br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center mb-2">
            <div class="col-sm-8 mb-4 shadow-lg p-3 bg-white rounded">
                <div class="header mb-2">
                    <h3 class="header mb-0 text-center">New Engineering Service Request</h3>
                    {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <small class="text-muted"><strong>Want to speed things up? </strong>
                            <a href="/login/?next=/esr_submit/"> Log In |</a>
                        </small>
                        <small class="text-muted">
                            <a href="/register/?next=/esr_submit/">Create an account </a>
                        </small>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="request_form"
                      class="request_form">
                    <div class="col">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% crispy request_form %}
                        <span class="helper-text"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="container">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-upload-photos">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload File(s)
                    </button>

                {# 2. FILE INPUT TO BE USED BY THE PLUG-IN #}
                    <form id="fileForm">
                      <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" class="file" multiple
                           style="display: none;"
                           data-url="{% url 'esr_submit:esr_submit' %}"
                           data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
                    </form>

                {# 3. TABLE TO DISPLAY THE UPLOADED FILES #}
                    <div id="myTable">
                        <table id="file-table" class="file-table table-borderless">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                                {% if photo in photos %}
                                <th>Attached Files</th>
                                {% else %}
                                {% endif %}
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody class="file-body">
                            {% for file in files %}
                              {% if file.file %}
                                <tr id="file-{{file.id}}"
                                    class="file">
                                    <td class="w-50">
                                      <a href="{{ file.file.url }}" target="_blank">{{ file.file }}</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="delete" id="delete">
                                        <button type=submit data-id="file-{{file.id}}" data-url="{% url 'esr_submit:delete_file' file.pk %}" class="file-delete-btn btn btn-danger btn-sm">X</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                              {% else %}
                              {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pl-2 mt-2">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit_request" value="submit_request" class="btn btn-primary" form="request_form">Submit Request</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="save_draft" value="save_draft" id="save_draft" class="btn btn-primary" form="request_form">Save Draft</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content%}
```

```
script.js (loaded on the base.html)

/* Multiple File Upload Using AJAX - FROM SIMPLE IS BETTER THAN COMPLEX EXAMPLE */
$(function fileupload() {
  /* 1. OPEN THE FILE EXPLORER WINDOW */
  $(".js-upload-photos").click(function () {
    $("#fileupload").click();
  });

  /* 2. INITIALIZE THE FILE UPLOAD COMPONENT */
  $("#fileupload").fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {  /* 3. PROCESS THE RESPONSE FROM THE SERVER */
      if (data.result.is_valid) {
        console.log(data)
        $("#file-table tbody").prepend(
          "<tr><td><a href='" + data.result.url + "' target='_blank'>" + data.result.name + "</a></td><td class='delete'><button type=submit data-id='file-{{file.id}}' data-url="{% url 'esr_submit:delete_file' file.pk %}" class='file-delete-btn btn btn-danger btn-sm'>X</button></td></tr>"
        )
      }
    }
  });
});


$('#myTable').on('click', '.file-delete-btn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var tableId = $(this).attr('file-table')
    var fileId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var formAction = $(this).attr('data-url');

        $.ajax({
        url: formAction,
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(){
            $("#file-" + fileId).remove()
            console.log("file removed")
            $("#myTable").load(" #myTable");
        },
        error: function(errorData){
            console.log("error")
            console.log(errorData)
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `{% url %}` tag in Javascript if this is a separate file.
If you just have a file `script.js`, it will not work.

In this case you want to generate the correct URL for the delete part. The best way to do this in the most reliable way (so it would still work if you edit the urls.py) is to use the Django urlresolvers.
Then return the data back to your upload process.

On the top of your Python file, place this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

The last bit of the POST-part in `esr_submit()` could look like this:

```py
        if 'file' in request.FILES:
            form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                file = form.save()
                data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': file.file.name, 'url': file.file.url, 'file_id': file.id, 'remove_url': reverse('esr_submit:delete_file', args=[file.id])}
            else:
                data = {'is_valid': False}
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            print("not a file form")
```

The Javascript bit could look like this:

```js
  /* 2. INITIALIZE THE FILE UPLOAD COMPONENT */
  $("#fileupload").fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {  /* 3. PROCESS THE RESPONSE FROM THE SERVER */
      if (data.result.is_valid) {
        $("#file-table tbody").prepend(
          "<tr><td><a href='" + data.result.url + "' target='_blank'>" + data.result.name + "</a></td><td class='delete'><button type=submit data-id='file-" + data.result.file_id + "' data-url='" + data.result.remove_url + "' class='file-delete-btn btn btn-danger btn-sm'>X</button></td></tr>"
        )
      }
    }
  });
```

I don't have your app running to this is from the top of my head.

Comment: Edited the question to add more context.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. For the {% url % } portion of the script, do I need to change the formatting at all for it to work properly?

Comment: I am very sorry, I understood it wrong (it from the AJAX upload call), I will update my comment again, just a minute

Comment: No worriesTo clarify, the way the {% url %} is written in the .prepend causes the script to stop working. If I remove it, the prepend operates as expected except of course the delete url isn't called resulting the desired delete action not happening

Comment: Yes I learned that from the context, I updated the answer

Comment: It worked, just had to edit 'file_id' and args to equal file.id in lieu of file.file.pk. Thank you so much for the quick responses. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks! Great that I have pushed you in the right direction and thanks for proposing the edit, I approved it. This can help others :-)